# Angular Express proper way to download file from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically the code below works. I click on button, the button sends the filePath data to the server. The server method `res.download` send the file as string. And then on the client a create anchor with href and download attributes. But when i try to download `.xls` file or `.zip` it downloads them but they are corrupted. I guess

```
'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(response)
```

is causing a problem when the file is not .txt or .log

Server:

```
app.post('/download', (req, res) => {
        let file = path.join(__dirname, 'public/files', req.body.filePath);
        res.download(file, req.body.filePath);
});
```

Client:

```
function downloadFile(filePath) {
        return $http({
            url: '/download',
            method: "POST",
            data: { filePath: filePath }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch(err => console.err);
}

function fileDownload(filePath, fileExtension) {
        let file = filePath + '.' + fileExtension;
        downloadFile(file).then((response) => {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
            a.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(response));
            a.setAttribute('download', (filePath || 'Export') + '.' + fileExtension)
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        });
    }
```